# Javascript: mapping each country of an array to each color of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays basically countries and colors, and I want to bind each of item of both the array. I tried with one function but doesn't work...

```
function mapColor(){
   var countries = ["UK", "INDIA", "FRANCE", "CHINA"];
   var colors = ["#807dba", "#41ab5d", "#DECF3F", "#FAA43A"];

   var obj ={};

   for(i=0, j=0; i<countries.length; i++, j<colors.length, j++){
         obj[countries[i]] = colors[j]; 
   }
    return obj;
   };
```

and expected object should be.

```
 {"UK":"#807dba","INDIA":"#41ab5d","FRANCE":"#DECF3F","CHINA":"#FAA43A"}
```

Comment: It is just a Simple loop, use i for both, not sure what you are expecting that for loop to do like that.

Comment: whats not working, your function outputs your expected result.

Comment: it loops 16 times... thats why..

Comment: no..it loops only 4 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made it overly complicated.

```
for (i=0; i<countries.length; i++){
    obj[countries[i]] = colors[i]; 
}
```

or

```
countries.forEach( function (val, ind){ obj[val] = colors(ind); });
```

Comment: Yah right!, Just need to know that how the result being generated without having  loop of color array?

Comment: You are looping it... You do not need two different loops when one can loop both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like:

```
function mapColor(){
   var countries = ["UK", "INDIA", "FRANCE", "CHINA"],
       colors = ["#807dba", "#41ab5d", "#DECF3F", "#FAA43A"];

    return countries.reduce(function(obj, country, index){
      obj[country] = colors[index];

      return obj;
    }, {});
   };
```

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) has to reduce it to a single
>   value.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are defining the arrays in the same function, why not just do the following:

```
function mapColor() {
   var obj = {};

   obj['UK'] = '#807dba';
   ...

   return obj;
}
```

or if the arrays are going to be passed in, then:

assuming the arrays are always supposed to be of the same length:

```
function mapColor(countries, colors) {
   var obj = {};

   if (countries.length != colors.length) {
       alert('Countries and Colors array should be of the same length');
       return null;
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
      obj[countries[i]] = colors[i];
   }

   return obj;
}
```

if it can't be guaranteed that they will be of the same length:

```
function mapColor(countries, colors) {
   var minLength = Math.min(countries.length, colors.length),
       obj = {};


   for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
      obj[countries[i]] = colors[i];
   }

   return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var countries = ["UK", "INDIA", "FRANCE", "CHINA"];
var colors = ["#807dba", "#41ab5d", "#DECF3F", "#FAA43A"];
var result = [];

$.each(countries, function(index, value){
    result[value] = colors[index];
});

console.info(result);

// Result : [UK: "#807dba", INDIA: "#41ab5d", FRANCE: "#DECF3F", CHINA: "#FAA43A"]
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using jQuery? And your result is an array and not an object.